# Knockout js $root $parent keyword

Tags: knockout.js

i am learning Knockout js. so reading many article and code from various source.
i just got a small code with Knockout js. i have confusion to understand few area in that code. which i will highlight and some one please help me to understand.

here is the full code

### html

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: {data: links, afterAdd: $root.fadeIn, afterRemove: $root.fadeOut}">
    <li>
        <select>
            <option>Homepege</option>
            <option>Facebook</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" />
        <button class="close" data-bind="click: $root.removeLink">&times;</button>
    </li>
</ul>
<a href="#" data-bind="click: addLink">Add Link</a>
```

### knockoutjs

```
function Link(id, url) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = id;
    self.url = url;
}

function VenueCreateViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.links = ko.observableArray([new Link("", "")]);
    //self.linksList = ko.observableArray(['Homepage11','Facebook']);
    self.removeLink = function (link) {
        self.links.remove(link)
    }
    self.addLink = function () {
        self.links.push(new Link("", ""));
    }

    self.fadeIn = function (element, index, data) {
        //$(element).fadeIn();
        $(element).filter("li").delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);
    }
    self.fadeOut = function (element, index, data) {
        $(element).filter("li").delay(1000).fadeOut(1000);
    }
}
ko.applyBindings(new VenueCreateViewModel());
```

1)
see this code `data-bind="foreach: {data: links, afterAdd: $root.fadeIn, afterRemove: $root.fadeOut}"`

why one need to point a function name with $root keyword ?

i point function name in binding this way `data-bind="foreach: {data : rows, beforeRemove : ElementFadeOut, afterAdd:ElementFadeIn}"` and it works.
so tell me when to refer or point a function name with `$root keyword` ?

2) i have some time seen people use $parent keyword. so tell me what is the difference between `$root & $parent keyword` ?

3) see this code `self.links = ko.observableArray([new Link("", "")]);`
why they push `link object into observable Array` where we can simply push any `string into links observable Array` ?

4) they use `fadeIn & fadeOut` `$(element).filter("li").delay(1000).fadeOut(1000);` but why fadeout effect is not working...any clue ?

here is jsfiddle link from where any one can see and run full code
http://jsfiddle.net/mfrsousa/2gt4K/3/

thanks

### Edit

i have couple of question based on jsfiddle link supplied by @Super cool

1) why your refer `firstName` property name in binding

```
<span data-bind="text:$data.firstName">
```

see the below code and this way i bind. here u can see i did not mention property name like `first name or last name`

```
<div id="dash" data-bind="foreach: {data : rows, beforeRemove : ElementFadeOut, afterAdd:ElementFadeIn}">
        <div data-bind="text:$data">
</div>
```

so please tell me why your mention property name in binding like `first name or last name` ??

2) i have seen the **jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/2gt4K/27/**
there i have seen the usage of `$parent $root keyword` usage but do not understand what is the difference between these keywords `$parent & $root keyword`

from your example it seems both keywords `$parent & $root keyword` works same way. can you tell me what is the difference between ?

Comment: You should check out the documentation:  http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html and http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html#note-1-passing-a-current-item-as-a-parameter-to-your-handler-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try .

1. $root refers to root content of viewModel always even $data represents the same but it tend to change based on the view you build .
2. $parent will look one step ahead of $data i.e if you have multiple looping instances

**VM:**

```
    var mainLoopModel = function () {
        var self = this; // Root Level scope
        self.mainloop = ko.observableArray([{
            'firstName': 'jhon'
        }, {
            'firstName': 'sam'
        }]);
        self.lastName = ko.observable('peters');
    }

    ko.applyBindings(new mainLoopModel());
```

**View:**

```
   <div data-bind="foreach:mainloop">
    $data Value: <span data-bind="text:$data.firstName"></span> 
                  <span data-bind="text:$data.lastName"></span> --(1)
    $parent Value: <span data-bind="text:firstName"> </span> 
                   <span data-bind="text:$parent.lastName"></span>
    $root Value: <span data-bind="text:firstName"></span>
                 <span data-bind="text:$root.lastName"></span>
   </div>
```

**Note:** If you remove $data before lastName in note (1) you get undefined error because mainloop dont have lastName , root model has lastName so you have to access using parent or higher level

sample fiddle for you **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/2gt4K/27/)**

3. `self.links = ko.observableArray([new Link("", "")]);` here we are assigning data rather pushing . yes we can use normal strings but we should sacrifice 2-way binding and your idea works well if you just binding the data to view which is where user cannot change .
4. A small mistake there you should be using `beforeRemove` not `afterRemove` .
   working demo **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/2gt4K/22/)**

Refer the docs **[here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html)** which is crystal clear to understand.

Comment: why do when need to say $data.mainloop rather we can simply say `<div data-bind="foreach: mainloop">` ? what is the difference between $data & $parent ?

Comment: i checked your js fiddle link and notice fadeIn() function is not working when adding data clicking on add link button. what causes the problem.

Comment: what u try to mean `$parent.subloop` ?

Comment: see there is no need for $data usually but its a best practice using `$data.mainloop` which eliminates the risk when something become undefined . diff b/w parent & data is simple $data refers to current context where as $parent refers to observables available outer to current context .

Comment: i just corrected `fadeout`  issue that's what troubling you as mentioned in your post . i haven't done anything to fadein i left as it is like in your fiddle

Comment: how did u correct the fadeout...tell me so i can correct fadein too that way.

Comment: u could explain with small example the significance of using the $Parent keyword and also why u wrote like this way `foreach:$data.mainloop` rather u could write `foreach:$data`. if possible come with a details explanation with more sample code which help me to understand the significance of using the `$Parent keyword` and `foreach:$data.mainloop`. thanks

Comment: fiddle.net is down i guess i cant access it . just i used beforeRemove instead of afterRemove . which does the trick

Comment: now see the updated answer which should bring some clarity for you cheers .

Comment: i have seen your jsfiddle link and again post some question on that topic. so please see my edit section in my post and answer those question please. thanks

Answer (score 3):

1. The `forEach` binding creates a new child binding context. When the binding renders an item, the context's `$data` property against which binding expressions are evaluated by default refers to the list item rather than your view-model. Therefore if you need to refer to your view-model inside a foreach binding you need to reference the parent binding context - which in many cases is equal to the root binding context. You can find a thorough explanations of Knockout's Binding Context [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html).
2. Again, read [this](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html)
3. Because `Link` is a class that combines an url with an id.
4. What is not working? If by not working you refer to the element remaining in the DOM after it has faded, please be advised that you are responsible for removing the element from the DOM after your animation has completed. Again, [read the documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html).

Comment: fadein and fadeout effect is not working if u run code from jsfiddle.

Comment: i point function name in binding this way data-bind="foreach: {data : rows, beforeRemove : ElementFadeOut, afterAdd:ElementFadeIn}" and it works. so tell me why some one point a function name with $root keyword ? they could simply refere function like this way `beforeRemove : ElementFadeOut` instead of `beforeRemove : $root.ElementFadeOut`

Comment: in the above case $root & $data acts in same way . if you have same above content inside some loop i.e `data-bind="foreach:array"`$data fails where $root works because in viewmodel `self.beforeRemove` is declared which is root . .

Comment: @supercool can u plzz make me understand with small complete sample code and also provide jsfiddle link.